# Program won't exit in using Callable and Future

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, future, callable

IDE: IntelliJ
JDK: Java 11

While was testing a sample code from lecture, I have found something really weird that my program just won't stop, even though there aren't any loop!

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class FindMaxTask implements Callable<Integer> {
    private int[] data;
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public FindMaxTask(int[] data, int start, int end) {
        this.data = data;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Integer call() {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (data[i] > max) {
                max = data[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

This is a `FindMaxTask` that implements `Callable` interface which performs a finding maximum value in given range of array.

```
public static void testCallable() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final int dataSize = 10000;
        int[] data = new int[dataSize];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
            data[i] = random.nextInt(1000000);
        }

        FindMaxTask task0 = new FindMaxTask(data, 0, dataSize / 2);
        FindMaxTask task1 = new FindMaxTask(data, dataSize / 2, dataSize);

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        Future<Integer> future0 = service.submit(task0);
        Future<Integer> future1 = service.submit(task1);

        int ret0 = future0.get();
        int ret1 = future1.get();

        System.out.println("ret0: " + ret0 + System.lineSeparator() + "ret1: " + ret1);
    }
```

This is a `testCallable` static function in Main class.

If I run `testCallable` function in main function, program just stops after printing each ret value in console.

Is this problem has something to do with `Callable` or `Future`? (I have tried debugging `future1.isDone()` with value of `true` after printing ret0,ret1 so it clearlly doesn't seems like that chlid thread has been blocked)
Please give me an advise why is this happening

Comment: You have to shut down the thread pool. Otherwise, you still have non-daemon threads running in the background. The JVM doesn't exit until all non-daemon threads have stopped.

Comment: @DavidConrad I thought child threads will vanish after main thread is exited, is this a special feature of JVM?

Comment: Child threads only vanish after main thread is exited if they are daemon threads. This is true since Java 1.0. See [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) is documented as saying that "The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to shut down the thread pool. Otherwise, you still have non-daemon threads running in the background. The JVM doesn't exit until all non-daemon threads have stopped.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
try {
    // do things with the executor service
} finally {
    service.shutdown();
}
```

If you want to block until all tasks have completed, you can use [`awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), or call [`shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) and then loop until [`isTerminated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#isTerminated--) returns true. If you want to try to terminate any running or queued tasks immediately, you can use [`shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--).

Comment: If tasks were runnable then it would be a good idea to use `service.awaitTermination(..)`

Comment: @onkarruikar There's no need. The main method isn't going to do any more work that depends on the tasks having completed, and besides, the code is already calling get() on the futures it created. But if for some reason you needed it to block until the tasks were completed, you could use awaitTermination.

Comment: @DavidConrad Since there is no downside to using `awaitTermination`, I suggest teaching its use as a good habit. Deserves at least a mention in your good Answer.

Comment: And, by the way, if [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) succeeds, this code becomes a bit simpler as `ExecutorService` will be [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) for use in [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax. Experimental builds available now based on early-access Java 18.

Comment: @BasilBourque I will add a mention of it, but I don't see how it's a good habit. If you don't want to block until all the tasks are completed, there is no reason to. I wonder if there is a misconception here that `shutdown` somehow kills running tasks, or prevents queued tasks from executing? It does not.